# Arrow function with return assignment not working even with parenthesis

Tags: javascript

I have the following filter:

```
const auxHash = {};
myArray.filter(house =>
  house.members === 3 &&
  auxHash[house.id] ? false : auxHash[house.id] = true
)
```

And I get a lint error saying that an arrow function should not return an assignment. I have tried this too:

```
const auxHash = {};
myArray.filter(house =>
  house.members === 3 &&
  auxHash[house.id] ? false : (auxHash[house.id] = true)
)
```

But same problem.  How can I solve this?

To clarify. I am trying to filter out elements of an array which attribute `members` is different than `3`, and also I am trying to remove duplicate elements based on the attribute `id` (that's why I am using the hash).

Comment: There is no return when you use {}

Comment: It's valid JavaScript, but is not good code when used as the return value of an arrow function, as the error says...

Comment: Updated, I wasn't using `{}` even though I tried that too with explicit `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before question edit.

If you use `{}` body you need explicitly return a result from that function.

```
const auxHash = {};
myArray.filter(house => {
    return house.members === 3 && auxHash[house.id] ? false : auxHash[house.id] = true;
})
```

Also, if your statement is one line, you can omit the `{}` part and remove `return`

```
const auxHash = {};
myArray.filter(house => house.members === 3 && auxHash[house.id] ? false : auxHash[house.id] = true)
```

Comment: The linter is complaining if I do what you suggest. Still saying that should not return an assignment.

Comment: The linter is right, generally you're not supposed to modify array elements inside a filter function

Comment: I'm not modifying an array element. I'm modifying a hash that I am not filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You're reformatting the exact same statement and ignoring the linter's error. You are returning an assignment. That is your problem. You're doing it right here - `auxHash[house.id] = true`

Your ternary resolves to false or `auxHash[house.id] = true`

So, refactor to return an actual value -

```
const auxHash = {};
myArray.filter(house => {
  if(house.members === 3 && auxHash[house.id]) {
      return false;
  } else {
      auxHash[house.id] = true;
      return true;
  }
});
```

You can write it more concisely but I stretched it out to make it clear.